# PHP MVC - Multiple models with same dependencies

Tags: php, model-view-controller, dependencies

I have recently started to work on creating a MVC PHP private framework (I know, there is no classical MVC in PHP, you guys understand what I mean by MVC in PHP).

I have encountered a problem, I know that a single controller can load multiple models for specific tasks. That's ok, but what happens when my models should load the same libraries/dependencies? Eg:

```
<?php

abstract class Model {

  protected $db = null;
  protected $validator = null;
  protected $validations = null;

  protected function _startDb() {

    if ( $this->db === null ) {

      $this->db = new Db();
    }
  }

  protected function _startValidator() {

    if ( $this->validator === null ) {

      $this->validator = new Validator();
    }
  }

  protected function _startValidations() {

    if ( $this->validations === null ) {

      self::_startValidator();
      $this->validations = new Validations($this->validator);
    }
  }

  // I have more functions like these, as you can see, they load needed libraries.
}

// Now my models which they all need some of these libraries that are loaded in model class.

class Roles extendes Model {

  public function getRoles() {

    // Makes use of _startDb(), _startValidations()... 
  }
}

class Permissions extends Model {

  public functoin getPermissions() {

   // Also makes use of _startDb(), _startValidations()...
  }
}
```

Well, I find no problem with this code as long as my controller just load one model. But it's not clear to me, and this is what bothers me, **if I load multiple models in one controller, then it means that each model have its own instance of each library.**

I do not like that, because specially db queries will get slower.

**So my question, what is the best way to keep things well organized and have one instance of each library and share them among multiple models.**

*Btw, I know about dependency injection, but some models would need to get like 4 libraries and thats feels wrong to me. And then I feel like the controller would have load all the libraries, and I do not know if thats ok.*

Comment: Err, inject the same `Db` instance into all the models ?

Comment: Multiple models would have to get `Db(), Validator(), Validations(), Session(), Rbac()` injected... That feels wrong.

Comment: @VictorTello, this phrase "have one instance of each library and be able to load multiple models" seems to be confusing. You want to share single instances of `Db` , `Validator` among multiple models ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Yes, I want just one instance of each library, and share those among multiple models. Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: @VictorTello, just instantiate all the service objects(libraries) once before instantiating multiple model objects. Then pass them as dependency injection

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest So I should instantiate all of them in the controller. Is that ok?

Comment: usually, a client is requesting one action from controller at a time. So you can set those service objects once within controller's `__construct` or `init` method

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Yeah, I was thinking of that... Thanks for your help.

Comment: I would recommend to look at this SO post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5863870/how-should-a-model-be-structured-in-mvc